# How to compare two directories, and if they're the EXACT SAME, delete the second

Tags: bash, unix, scripting, directory

I'm trying to setup an automatic backup on a raspberry pi system connected to an external hard drive.

Basically, I have shared folders and they're mounted via samba on the rPI under

```
/mnt/Comp1

/mnt/Comp2
```

I will then have the external hard drive plugged in and mounted with two folders under

```
/media/external/Comp1
/media/external/Comp2
```

I will then run a recursive copy from /mnt/Comp1* to /media/external/Comp1/* and the same with Comp2.

---

What I need help with is at the end of the copies (because it will be a total of 5 computers), I would like to verify that all the files transferred, and if they did and everything is on the external, then I can delete from the local machine automatically. I understand this is risky, because almost inevitably it will delete things that may not be backed up, but I need help knowing where to start.

I've found a lot of information on checking contents of a folder, and I know I can use the diff command, but I don't know how to use it in this pseudocode

```
use diff on directories /mnt/Comp1/ and /media/external/Comp1

if no differences, proceed to delete /mnt/Comp1/* recursively

if differences, preferably move the files not saved to /media/external/Comp1

repeat checking for differences, and deleting if necessary
```

Comment: Have you tried `if diff -q /path/dir1 /path/dir2; then rm -r /path/dir2; fi` (to delete `dir2` if `dir1` and `dir2` are the same? `man diff` is pretty good at explaining the options. Use `else` to effect the move if differences are found.

Comment: I appreciate your prompt reply. I will test this later on the system itself, it seems like this would work, since I just tested it on my local computer. What does fi do? and also, if it's there's no difference, does the copy command have a way to skip duplicateS? I guess I can look into this. Thanks again!!

Could I do else cp -n /path/dir1/* /path/dir2/* ?

Comment: This is a solved problem. Use `rsync`.

Comment: @chepner I have used rsync in my localhost using `rsync -r --ignore-existing --delete-during ./local/ ./external/`' --- however, it doesn't delete the local folder before hand. Could you assist me with this last thing?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
 diff -r -q d1/ d2/ >/dev/null 2>&1
```

check return value with $?
     remove the d2, if return value is 1.